# TensorFlow.js returns always the same wrong prediction (although the underlying Python-model works fine)

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, ionic-framework, neural-network, tensorflow.js

I have to develop a mobile application with the Ionic Framework (so the code is completely written in HTML and JavaScript/TypeScript) which uses neural networks for image classification.
So I've trained a simple model with only 3 classes in Python and tested it - it works nearly perfect, every tested image is classified correctly with 90-100% accuracy.

So I converted the trained Keras-Model into JSON, but when I classify one of the same images as in the Python-tests in my Ionic-App I get the same wrong result, which is something like this:

`[9.851827087459242e-8, 0.000011355405149515718, 0.9999885559082031]`

There may be a small difference between the values, but every time the third value is something like 0.999..., so every image is classified as the same (wrong) class.

I tried to draw an image to HTML-Canvas and read it:

```js
var canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.getElementById('imageCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var imgElem = <HTMLImageElement> document.getElementById('imgID');
ctx.drawImage(imgElem , 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
const imgData: ImageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

After that I converted the imageData into the correct input shape for the neural network:

```js
let img = tf.browser.fromPixels(imgData, 3);
img = img.reshape([-1, 192, 192, 3]);
img = tf.cast(img, 'float32');
```

Finally I get the prediction results with this function:

```js
const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('../../assets/tfjs_model/model.json').then(model => {
    const output = model.predict(smallImg) as any;
    var prediction = Array.from(output.dataSync()); 
});
```

I also tried to read the img-Data directly through the img-tag/URL (as HTMLImageElement instead of HTMLCanvasElement), because I heard that I have to ensure that the image has loaded completely:

```js
const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('../../assets/tfjs_model/model.json');
imgData.onload = function () {
    let img = tf.browser.fromPixels(imgData, 3);
    img = img.reshape([-1, 192, 192, 3]);
    img = tf.cast(img, 'float32');

    const output = model.predict(img) as any;
    var prediction = Array.from(output.dataSync()); 
}
imgData.src = "../../assets/img/img1.jpg";
```

But unfortunately this solution leads to the same wrong results as mentioned above...

I've already read every question and answer to this topic on Stackoverflow and some other pages, but every try turns into the same bad result.

So I really hope that someone can help me to find another solution or to find out what's wrong with my code.

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**

My Python-code looks like this (an extract of it):

Before the training I do this:

```js
img = cv2.imread(path,1)
img = cv2.resize(img, (192, 192), 3)
test_images.append([np.array(img), one_hot_label(i)])
```

```js
tr_img_data = np.array([i[0] for i in training_images]).reshape(-1,192,192,3)
tr_lbl_data = np.array([i[1] for i in training_images])
tst_img_data = np.array([i[0] for i in testing_images]).reshape(-1,192,192,3)
tst_lbl_data = np.array([i[1] for i in testing_images])

input_shape = tr_img_data.shape[1:]

tr_img_data = tr_img_data.astype('float32')
tst_img_data = tst_img_data.astype('float32')
```

After that the setup of the model begins.

And in my code for the testing/use of the trained model I do this:

```js
img = cv2.imread(file,1)
img = cv2.resize(img, (192, 192), 3)
img = img.reshape((-1, img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 3))
img = img.astype("float")
```

After that I return the img and call the function for the prediction.

Comment: Are you processing the image that comes in the same way that you did in Python? Previously I had the same issue where the output was almost identical to your output and it was due to me not processing the incoming tensor in the same manner as I did when training the model.

Comment: Good idea, before I asked my question I had already found one mistake at this point, actually (in Python I normalized the float-data by division by 255), but fixed it and now I cannot see an inconsistency anymore... I edited my post to show you an extract of my Python-code, so maybe you can see if there's another mistake.

Comment: It would be easier for a start if you could include the shape of the image before you send it to the model in the Python implementation compared to the ionic implementation.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I don't really understand what you mean... I do nothing with the images except from the stuff in the code above, so what you can see there is the shape of the image before I send it to the model (both in TypeScript and in Python).

Comment: I've got an additional information: A plain black image in the canvas leads to a result where every class is preditced with a probability of about 1/3. And if I use grayscale images (with a Python-model trained with such images), everything seems to work fine - so I think there might be a problem with the color channels?

Comment: These are RGB images that you built the model on right? That is why I asked for the shapes of the images from both applications right before being passed to the model.

Comment: Yes, that's right, I used RGB images both for my Python-model and the Ionic app and now I changed them into grayscale in both applications.

Comment: Now something weird happened: I remembered that OpenCV (in my Python code) changes the color channels From RGB to BGR. So I switched the channels in TypeScript manually, but that didn't solve the problem. Then I tried to switch the channels to BRG and now it seems to work fine...?

Comment: I solved the problem by myself: When I changed the color channels to BGR I forgot that I don't use a copy of the original data, so I only set channel 1 and 3 so that the green color channel was always 0. Now I set all the three channels in the correct way and it works perfectly with the BGR order!

Comment: Good to know apologies I just read your updates.

Comment: No problem, the main thing is that I solved my issue (I'm thankful nevertheless). :)